# Problem in VHDL std_logic_vector place values

Tags: vector, vhdl

I am having problems detecting the place values of the binary number stored in the std_logic_vector format. For example in the code below I am trying to see what the value in INST_SPEED is, between 0 to 99 km/h. The code is really long with many if conditions.

```
if INST_SPEED > "0001001" and INST_SPEED < "0010100" then           -- if INST_SPEED > 9 & INST_SPEED < 20

       UPPER10 <= "0000001";                    -- UPPER10 = 1
       TEMP    <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(INST_SPEED) - 10);
       UPPER1 <= TEMP;                      -- LOWER10 = INST_SPEED - 10
      elsif INST_SPEED > "0010011" and INST_SPEED < "0011110" then  -- if INST_SPEED > 19 & INST_SPEED < 30
       UPPER10 <= "0000010";                    -- UPPER10 = 2
       TEMP    <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(INST_SPEED) - 20);
       UPPER1 <= TEMP;                      -- LOWER10 = INST_SPEED - 20
      elsif INST_SPEED > "0011101" and INST_SPEED < "101000" then   -- if INST_SPEED > 29 & INST_SPEED < 40
       UPPER10 <= "0000011";                    -- UPPER10 = 3
       TEMP    <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(INST_SPEED) - 30);
       UPPER1 <= TEMP;                      -- LOWER10 = INST_SPEED - 30
```

However, now i have to write a similar code for detecting a value in the range from 0-999. If i go by this logic, that will mean 90 such if conditions!

Does anyone know of a simpler more intelligent way of going about this process? This would really help me out, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change the problem.  I suggest either implementing a modulo function to convert from your binary value to a base-ten value (this could be pretty small if it doesn't have to update quickly) or it may be easier use BCD for the INST_SPEED value.

As you're coding things now, you really need a divide/modulo function, which is what you're trying to hard-code with all your conditionals.  Depending on your target, you may be able to do this for "free" (ie: perhaps the FPGA you're using has unused hardware multipliers available?).

Comment: Hey, yeah i was thinking of this problem last night while trying to sleep. I think it is simpler to divide each number in turn first by 100, and then by 10. So for eg, take the no. 721, after the first division, i will get 7 as the answer (hundreds place value) and 21 as the remainder. Then i divide the remainder by 10 to get 2 as the tens value and finally 1 as the units or ones value.

Answer (score 0):

Couple options I can think of:

1. How about creating a large LUT (lookup table) which will be stored in a ROM? The address would be the INST_SPEED value, and the output would be UPPER10 or TEMP. You could generate the ROM contents with a script (outside of VHDL) and then paste it into your code, or load from a file with VHDL file IO support.
2. Is there really no simple pattern between the inputs and outputs? Is this some math function that you could derive instead?